# TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 1, 4), dtype=float32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I use keras to complete the TCN model on the server, I get an error at runtime, I think it is an error caused by the version, because there is no error on the local, this confuses me so much
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxG9m.png)[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzxGO.png)

I hope to fix this error

Comment: please add the code as text and not as images, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)